# Show object value every 5 seconds in jquery.each

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of like 5 items which i want to show for 5 seconds every item.
Here is the following HTML code:

```
<div class="show">
 <rec>First item</rec>
 <rec>Second item</rec>
 <rec>Third item</rec>
 <rec>Fourth item</rec>
 <p class="show-line"></p>
</div>
```

And here the Jquery

```
 $('.show > rec').hide();

 $('rec').each(function(index) { 
  var x = $(this).text();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('p.show-line').html(x).fadeIn('slow');  
    }, 5000);

 });
```

Now the problem is that only the last item is outputted in the show-line element.
But when i am alerting the x element its outputs the right value. So how can i show each element for like 5 seconds then hide and shows the next element and so on...

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/3NnR2/11/

Tnx

Comment: **every 5 seconds** is `setInterval`, the **next 5 seconds** is `setTimeout`

Comment: btw, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13967834/28004) on other question and my [live example](http://jsbin.com/osepim/1/edit). maybe you are trying to get something like that... no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method then pick the element you want to show based on index:

```
$('.show > rec').hide();

var index = 0;
var total = $('rec').size() - 1;

setInterval(function(){

    var rec = $('rec:eq(' + index + ')');
    $('p.show-line').html(rec.text()).fadeIn("slow");

    if(index == total){
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index++;
    }

}, 5000);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3NnR2/15/

Comment: For the fading effect the hide() function is needed. So the line will be
$('p.show-line').html(rec.text()).hide().fadeIn('slow');

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need a different setTimeout interval for each one.
2. You'll also need to `.hide()` the element before `.fadeIn()`

Try the following:

```
$('.show > rec').hide();

$('rec').each(function(index) { 
    var x = $(this).text();
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('p.show-line').html(x).hide().fadeIn('slow');  
     }, index * 5000);

});
```

Comment: really good, that works! How can i make this loop continues so after the last element the first starts again?

Comment: Using SetInterval will keep looping through the items, see my answer for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple of things wrong here.

1. no document ready function
2. you're calling the `fadeIn` on the wrong element (`.show-line` instead of `rec`)

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/3NnR2/13/) how could actually do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show > rec').hide();
    showNext($("rec:first-child"));

});

function showNext($ele){
    $ele.fadeIn('slow'); 
    if ($ele.next("rec").length > 0)
         setTimeout(function() {
           showNext($ele.next("rec"))  
         }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my answer in as well. Looks like this was a popular one, and it's interesting to see the various techniques used.

```
var i = 0;
var items = [];

$('.show > rec').hide();

$('rec').each(function(index) {
    var x = $(this).text();
    items[items.length] = x;
});

function rotate() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (i > items.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $('p.show-line').html(items[i]).hide().fadeIn('slow');
        i++;
        rotate();
    }, 5000);
}

rotate();​
```

The basic idea is just to populate the items into an array and just loop through them forever using recursion. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3NnR2/17/